# Is conversion `operator void()` allowed?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer

I'm currently studying C++ standard and came to this insane example:

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 0;

class A {
public:
    operator void() {
        std::cout << ++i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() { 
    A a, b;
    A c = (a, b);
    static_cast<void>(a);
    (void) a;
}
```

Despite the fact that `operator void()` has side effects, it is never called (at least nothing is printed to stdout). However `operator void()` is not disallowed, the only way I found to trigger it is to use volatiles:

> **5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]**
>
> [...]
>   Any expression can be explicitly converted to type *cv* `void`, in which case it becomes a *discarded-value expression* (Clause 5).
>
> **5  Expressions [expr]**
>
> [...]
>   The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied if and
>   only if the expression is a glvalue of volatile-qualified type and it is one of the following: [...]

<sup>As of N3797 draft</sup>

I have tried to add `volatile` to my code, but nothing printed.

Is there way to trigger `operator void()` or it is dead code? Of course question is speculative, no practical use behind it.

I have checked my example with G++ 4.9 and CLang++ 3.3

Comment: Well you can always just call `a.operator void()`, but that's boring.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what does `A c = (a, b);` do (I know this has nothing to do with his question)? That is some kind of copy constructor ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun that.s just copy construct `c` from `b`, `,` is just comma operator here.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I have missed that part in 12.3.2.

Comment: @ForEveR what does `a`do there ?

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun It does nothing. It evaluates `a`, and then discards it. That's the point of the question: the OP hoped to trigger the `operator void()` conversion operator by discarding the value in that way.